# Sending email with PHPMailer and marking email as replied in O365

Tags: php, outlook, office365, phpmailer

I'm trying to reply to a message in one of my email accounts received and record the the message was replied to. The email sends fine but outlook doesn't flag the message as received. Also the original message is not marked as read.
I have google the heck out of it but can't find any definitive answers.
It is either so simple that no one really has this issue or it's not really possible.
I added the two custom headers

```
$mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To', $message_id);
$mail->addCustomHeader('References', $message_id);
```

My code is as follows and all seems to work fine, the message is seen in the sent items and I receive it but it's not mark as replied.
Also the original mail is not in the reply.

```
$message_id = "<lo2p123mb2223e640722ab92491ebf3a6f3660@lo2p123mb2223.gbrp123.prod.outlook.com>";

//phpmailer
require('class.phpmailer.php');
require('class.smtp.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username = "myusername";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "mypassword"; // SMTP password
$mail->From = 'recipent@myemail.com';
$mail->AddAddress('me@myemail.com'); 
$mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To', $message_id);
$mail->addCustomHeader('References', $message_id);
$mail->IsHTML(true);               
$mail->Subject = 'RE: test 2'; //subject as received email but with added "RE: "
$mail->Body    = 'some body here';

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent<br>";
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. The in-reply-to and references headers have nothing to do with marking messages as replied (see [this doc](https://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html)), and generally there is no such thing as a received flag at the message level, though clients usually keep their own records of read status that are accessible via IMAP, which PHPMailer has nothing to do with. You're also using a very old version of PHPMailer, which never helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Synchro. All I'm trying to do send a reply to a message I received and mark it so, but, rather than using outlook I'm using PHP. Also, sending the original message in the reply as any email client does. I will update PHPMailer too.

Comment: If you want to reply to existing messages, or change the status of things in outlook/exchange then I think you'd need to use the o365  Graph API provided by Microsoft. SMTP is (as the first letter of the acronym suggests) simple and purely sends messages. It doesn't record any kind of status about those messages in your inbox, and it cannot read existing messages in order to reply to them - it purely sends a single message as if it's a new thread. You're lucky it even shows in your sent items - many mail systems won't even record that if you send via raw SMTP.